# 'uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting an error that highlights

`<% count = @ current_profile.unread_message_count %>`

when I am not sure why = ( ! It works prefectly when I am not logged in, but none of the pages work when logged in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqSpN.png

Comment: post your model `message` and method `unread_message_count` from Profle model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tryout this gem (if you don't know it?). It will give you a more detailed description of what is wrong with your script: https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors